# scale_x_continuous function error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sort of new to R and would appreciate your help with my code.

I am drawing a heat map of my genes using this code

```
#Load required packages 
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")

#Load files
cellcycle1 <- read.csv("heatmap_log_4Fold_Above50.csv")

#Melt
cellcycle1.m <- melt(cellcycle1)

#arrange heat plot
order <- arrange(cellcycle1, X0, X30, X60, X90, X120, X150, X180, X210, X240)

#This changes the order of the Y axis based on the sort order
cellcycle1.m$Gene_ID <- factor(cellcycle1.m$Gene_ID, levels =  
order$Gene_ID, labels = order$Gene_ID)

#Draw Heat plot
(e <- ggplot(cellcycle1.m, aes(variable, Gene_ID)) + geom_tile(aes(fill =
value), colour = "white")
+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")) 
+ theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
axis.text.x = element_text(angle=50, size = 15, vjust=0.5)) 
+ labs(x= "Time", y = "Gene")
```

And here is my result
[image: Heat Plot]

My trouble comes when trying to rename the ticks on my x-axis with this function added to the end of my heat plot.

```
+ scale_x_continuous(label=function(x){return(paste(x, "Minutes"))})
```

And I get the error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Thanks ahead of time for any help or guidance you can give.

Comment: Is `variable` a factor or character? If so, you would need `scale_x_discrete` rather than `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: Thank you eipi, that worked. R is adding the "X" in X0, X30, ect. Do you know how I would remove that X?

Comment: R doesn't allow column names to start with a number, so I'd guess R is adding the `X` to the beginning of illegal column names when you read in the data. Use `check.names=FALSE` in `read.csv` to prevent this. That's the easiest way. However, for future reference, to remove the `X` after you read and melt the data, you could do this: `cellcycle1.m$variable = as.numeric(gsub("X(.*)", "\\1", cellcycle1.m$variable))` or `cellcycle1.m$variable = as.numeric(substr(cellcycle1.m$variable, 2, nchar(cellcycle1.m$variable)))`.

Comment: One more thing: Even if you use `check.names=FALSE` when you read in the data, after melting the data `variable` will be coded as a factor (a categorical variable) rather than as numeric. To fix this, do the following: `cellcycle1.m$variable = as.numeric(as.character(cellcycle1.m$variable))`.

Comment: Hey epipi, the "check.names=False" worked well for my first data set but when i tried to use it on another batch of data I can't order them with my order command. I used the other code you provided and got different errors but the same problem. The part where I am getting the errors is "order <- arrange(cellcycle1, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240)" and the error I am getting is "Error: incorrect size (1), expecting : 418". Any suggestions?